# What are the steps to create a radar chart in Bokeh python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, charts, visualization, bokeh

Objective: to create a radar chart within Bokeh python

To be helpful this is the chart type I am after:
[image]

I obtained [this chart example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/radar_chart.html) from Matplotlib which might be helpful in closing the gap on a solution, however I can't see how to get there.

Below is the closest example I could find to a radar chart using Bokeh:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from math import log, sqrt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from six.moves import cStringIO as StringIO

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

antibiotics = """
bacteria,                        penicillin, streptomycin, neomycin, gram
Mycobacterium tuberculosis,      800,        5,            2,        negative
Salmonella schottmuelleri,       10,         0.8,          0.09,     negative
Proteus vulgaris,                3,          0.1,          0.1,      negative
Klebsiella pneumoniae,           850,        1.2,          1,        negative
Brucella abortus,                1,          2,            0.02,     negative
Pseudomonas aeruginosa,          850,        2,            0.4,      negative
Escherichia coli,                100,        0.4,          0.1,      negative
Salmonella (Eberthella) typhosa, 1,          0.4,          0.008,    negative
Aerobacter aerogenes,            870,        1,            1.6,      negative
Brucella antracis,               0.001,      0.01,         0.007,    positive
Streptococcus fecalis,           1,          1,            0.1,      positive
Staphylococcus aureus,           0.03,       0.03,         0.001,    positive
Staphylococcus albus,            0.007,      0.1,          0.001,    positive
Streptococcus hemolyticus,       0.001,      14,           10,       positive
Streptococcus viridans,          0.005,      10,           40,       positive
Diplococcus pneumoniae,          0.005,      11,           10,       positive
"""

drug_color = OrderedDict([
    ("Penicillin",   "#0d3362"),
    ("Streptomycin", "#c64737"),
    ("Neomycin",     "black"  ),
])

gram_color = {
    "positive" : "#aeaeb8",
    "negative" : "#e69584",
}

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(antibiotics),
                 skiprows=1,
                 skipinitialspace=True,
                 engine='python')

width = 800
height = 800
inner_radius = 90
outer_radius = 300 - 10

minr = sqrt(log(.001 * 1E4))
maxr = sqrt(log(1000 * 1E4))
a = (outer_radius - inner_radius) / (minr - maxr)
b = inner_radius - a * maxr

def rad(mic):
    return a * np.sqrt(np.log(mic * 1E4)) + b

big_angle = 2.0 * np.pi / (len(df) + 1)
small_angle = big_angle / 7

p = figure(plot_width=width, plot_height=height, title="",
    x_axis_type=None, y_axis_type=None,
    x_range=(-420, 420), y_range=(-420, 420),
    min_border=0, outline_line_color="black",
    background_fill_color="#f0e1d2", border_fill_color="#f0e1d2",
    toolbar_sticky=False)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

# annular wedges
angles = np.pi/2 - big_angle/2 - df.index.to_series()*big_angle
colors = [gram_color[gram] for gram in df.gram]
p.annular_wedge(
    0, 0, inner_radius, outer_radius, -big_angle+angles, angles, color=colors,
)

# small wedges
p.annular_wedge(0, 0, inner_radius, rad(df.penicillin),
                -big_angle+angles+5*small_angle, -big_angle+angles+6*small_angle,
                color=drug_color['Penicillin'])
p.annular_wedge(0, 0, inner_radius, rad(df.streptomycin),
                -big_angle+angles+3*small_angle, -big_angle+angles+4*small_angle,
                color=drug_color['Streptomycin'])
p.annular_wedge(0, 0, inner_radius, rad(df.neomycin),
                -big_angle+angles+1*small_angle, -big_angle+angles+2*small_angle,
                color=drug_color['Neomycin'])

# circular axes and lables
labels = np.power(10.0, np.arange(-3, 4))
radii = a * np.sqrt(np.log(labels * 1E4)) + b
p.circle(0, 0, radius=radii, fill_color=None, line_color="white")
p.text(0, radii[:-1], [str(r) for r in labels[:-1]],
       text_font_size="8pt", text_align="center", text_baseline="middle")

# radial axes
p.annular_wedge(0, 0, inner_radius-10, outer_radius+10,
                -big_angle+angles, -big_angle+angles, color="black")

# bacteria labels
xr = radii[0]*np.cos(np.array(-big_angle/2 + angles))
yr = radii[0]*np.sin(np.array(-big_angle/2 + angles))
label_angle=np.array(-big_angle/2+angles)
label_angle[label_angle < -np.pi/2] += np.pi # easier to read labels on the left side
p.text(xr, yr, df.bacteria, angle=label_angle,
       text_font_size="9pt", text_align="center", text_baseline="middle")

# OK, these hand drawn legends are pretty clunky, will be improved in future release
p.circle([-40, -40], [-370, -390], color=list(gram_color.values()), radius=5)
p.text([-30, -30], [-370, -390], text=["Gram-" + gr for gr in gram_color.keys()],
       text_font_size="7pt", text_align="left", text_baseline="middle")

p.rect([-40, -40, -40], [18, 0, -18], width=30, height=13,
       color=list(drug_color.values()))
p.text([-15, -15, -15], [18, 0, -18], text=list(drug_color),
       text_font_size="9pt", text_align="left", text_baseline="middle")

output_file("burtin.html", title="burtin.py example")

show(p)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your example code is from [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/burtin.html) right? I think bokeh has no inbuild support for circular axis, so you basically have to build the everything yourself with the primitives.

Comment: This correct. It's possible [Holoviews](http://holoviews.org/) has some higher level capability built on top of Bokeh but I am not sure offhand. I would definitely be in favor of adding better support to core Bokeh for this, but there has not been a huge perceived demand, and there are many priorities and not enough people. Happy to help any new contributor that wants to work on it sooner, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an example similar based off the approach on the matplotlib example you linked above. This gets you quite close to what you want, you will need to fix up all of the formatting to make it look nicer, and also add in the contour lines.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LabelSet

num_vars = 9

centre = 0.5

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_vars, endpoint=False)
# rotate theta such that the first axis is at the top
theta += np.pi/2

def unit_poly_verts(theta, centre ):
    """Return vertices of polygon for subplot axes.
    This polygon is circumscribed by a unit circle centered at (0.5, 0.5)
    """
    x0, y0, r = [centre ] * 3
    verts = [(r*np.cos(t) + x0, r*np.sin(t) + y0) for t in theta]
    return verts

def radar_patch(r, theta, centre ):
    """ Returns the x and y coordinates corresponding to the magnitudes of 
    each variable displayed in the radar plot
    """
    # offset from centre of circle
    offset = 0.01
    yt = (r*centre + offset) * np.sin(theta) + centre 
    xt = (r*centre + offset) * np.cos(theta) + centre 
    return xt, yt

verts = unit_poly_verts(theta, centre)
x = [v[0] for v in verts] 
y = [v[1] for v in verts] 

p = figure(title="Baseline - Radar plot")
text = ['Sulfate', 'Nitrate', 'EC', 'OC1', 'OC2', 'OC3', 'OP', 'CO', 'O3','']
source = ColumnDataSource({'x':x + [centre ],'y':y + [1],'text':text})

p.line(x="x", y="y", source=source)

labels = LabelSet(x="x",y="y",text="text",source=source)

p.add_layout(labels)

# example factor:
f1 = np.array([0.88, 0.01, 0.03, 0.03, 0.00, 0.06, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00])
f2 = np.array([0.07, 0.95, 0.04, 0.05, 0.00, 0.02, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00])
f3 = np.array([0.01, 0.02, 0.85, 0.19, 0.05, 0.10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00])
f4 = np.array([0.02, 0.01, 0.07, 0.01, 0.21, 0.12, 0.98, 0.00, 0.00])
f5 = np.array([0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.71, 0.74, 0.70, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00])
#xt = np.array(x)
flist = [f1,f2,f3,f4,f5]
colors = ['blue','green','red', 'orange','purple']
for i in range(len(flist)):
    xt, yt = radar_patch(flist[i], theta, centre)
    p.patch(x=xt, y=yt, fill_alpha=0.15, fill_color=colors[i])
show(p)
```

[image: Radar example]